# Stop command after a given time and return its result in Bash

Tags: bash

I need to execute several calls to a C++ program that records frames from a videogame. I have about 1800 test games, and some of them work and some of them don't.

When they don't work, the console returns a Segmentation fault error, but when they do work, the program opens a window and plays the game, and at the same time it records every frame.

The problem is that when it does work, this process does not end until you close the game window.

I need to make a Bash script that will test every game I have and write the names of the ones that work in a text file and the names of the ones that don't work in another file.

For the moment I have tried with this, using the `timeout` command:

```
count=0
# Run for every file in the ROMS folder
for filename in ../ROMs/*.bin; do
    # Increase the counter
    (( count++ ))
    # Run the command with a timeout to prevent it from being infinite
    timeout 5 ./doc/examples/videoRecordingExample "$filename"
    # Check if execution succeeds/fails and print in a text file
    if [ $? == 0 ]; then
        echo "Game $count named $filename" >> successGames.txt
    else
        echo "Game $count named $filename" >> failedGames.txt
    fi
done
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, because it writes all the names on the same file. I believe this is because the condition inside the `if` refers to the timeout and not the execution of the C++ program itself.

Then I tried without the `timeout` and everytime a game worked, I closed manually the window, and then the result was the expected. I tried this with only 10 games, but when I test it with all the 1800 I would need it to be completely automatic.

So, is there any way of making this process automatic? Like some command to stop the execution and at the same time know if it was successful or not?

Comment: Maybe 'timeout --signal 9 --preserve-status ... etc.' would work better?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
timeout 5 ./doc/examples/videoRecordingExample "$filename"
```

you could try this:

```
./doc/examples/videoRecordingExample "$filename" && sleep 5 && pkill videoRecordingExample
```

Comment: I have tried this just now, and it's a bit weird because now I still have to close the game window manually, but then it waits 5 seconds to try the next game.

Answer (score 0):

Swap the arguments in the **timeout** code.  It should be:

```
timeout 5 "$filename" ./doc/examples/videoRecordingExample
```

Reason:  the syntax for **timeout** is:

> timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...

So the COMMAND should be just after the DURATION.  In the code above the presumably non-executable file *videoRecordingExample* would be the COMMAND, which probably returns an error every time.

Comment: The file videoRecordingExample works just fine, it has worked for me, I don't think that is the problem really... The problem is that I have to close the window manually if I want to go to the next game, and I would like for it to be all automatic. Also, "$filename" is the input parameter to the C++ program.

Comment: @MartaSampietro, you're saying that *videoRecordingExample* is an executable file C++ program?   It's in a 'doc' subfolder, so that isn't obvious.

Comment: Yeah, it works, and it is inside the doc/examples subfolders yes. Sorry if I didn't explain it well on the post, but yeah, the program works just fine, the only problem I have is that I don't know how to automatically abort its execution and know its status, in order to know what games work for the C++ program and what games don't.